# Obtaining Image File Metadata and Indexing to Solr using TikaEntityProcessor

Tags: image, apache, solr, indexing, metadata

Can someone suggest how to obtain the metadata of an image file (ex. .jpg, .png, .gif, etc) and index those data to Apache Solr?

Currently, I'm using Apache Solr 4.2. In the DataImport Configuration file (for me, i named it "db-import-config.xml"), I tried using TikaEntityProcessor with ImageMetadataExtractor.

```
<entity name="tika-test"
        dataSource="binary"      // using BinURLDataSource
        processor="TikaEntityProcessor"
        onError="skip"
        rootEntity="false"
        url="${dbmw_image.url}"
        format="none"
        parser="org.apache.tika.parser.image.ImageMetadataExtractor">
        <field column="contributor" name="authors" meta="true"/>
        <field column="creator" name="authors" meta="true"/>
        <field column="data" name="creationDate" meta="true"/>
        <field column="modified" name="lastModifiedDate" meta="true"/>
 </entity>
```

The field "column"'s are all from Dublin Core metadata list. When I tried dataimport on Solr, none of these fields were picked up. I need answers for the following questions:

1. What are the available metadata field NAMEs for image files? (i.e. the values that I can put in the "column" attribute of "field" in the Tika entity above)
2. How to index and obtain those metadata values (through Tika?) and index to Solr? (ex. Which parser do I need? How should I set the tika entity attributes, etc)

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at [TikaEntityProcessor documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/TikaEntityProcessor)?
Specifically [Finding field names](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/TikaEntityProcessor#Finding_field_names)?